# Fork V-Brakes won't come out

Tags: brakes, fork

I can't remove these v brakes out of my fork, any idea how to remove these?

Also, i unscrewed the bolts as you can see at the photo but still no go.[image]

Comment: Do you have replacement V brake arms to fit or are these going back on once cleaned up ?

Answer (score 4):

I've removed a few sets of v brakes and they always need a fair bit of force, pulling the entire brake arm away from the fork. It's easier if you remove the pads because you've got more room to twist as you pull, and more room to grip.

You can also try levering between the fork and the far side of the brake, but protect the fork with some thin wood and don't do that on really light forks (I've only had to remove them from them cheap steel bikes and from the remains of my decent but rugged aluminium hybrid).

Comment: yeah - there's likely some grooves worn in the surface, so the arm only needs to come off a tiny amount till there's two high spots meeting.  Answer - more force, and if it breaks they needed replacing anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Just figured it out, you need to pull them as hard as you could.

I also removed my rear brake that wont come off by hand, i first removed the rear wheel and used a rubber mallet to hit it where the mallet wont hit the bike frame.